# Is there a way to count unique values in column X where Y and Z match set criteria?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of data with A, B, C and D where there are lots of duplicate names. I want to count each name only once, if B and C matches kriteria set.

Example:

- Peter - Clerk - Working - Male
- Peter - Clerk - Working - Male
- Steve - Clerk - Working - Male
- John - Manager - Working - Male
- John - Manager - Working - Male
- Dave - Clerk - Working - Male

I have tried various Sum's and Countifs, and manage to count the amount of unique encounters for each name, but when i try to add filters for "clerk" and "working" i fail in making a coherent formula.

```
{=SUM(1/(COUNTIF(Avdelingsmøte_FK!Deltaker,Avdelingsmøte_FK!Deltaker)))}
```

The kriteria are set to be Clerk and Working, so i expect the count to return 3. With my current formula i get 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the numerator as a filter then change the COUNTIF to a COUNTIFS and supplement with the condions and finally add the inverse of the numerator into the denomonator.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((B2:B7="clerk")*(C2:C7="working"))/(COUNTIFS(A2:A7,A2:A7,B2:B7,"clerk",C2:C7,"working")+((B2:B7<>"clerk")+(C2:C7<>"working"))))
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain how the last part of the formula works? the (c2:c7<>"working"). I am trying to adapt the formula to work with numbers (so instead of working the values i'm looking for would be >0.